# My bookmarks can't be accessed after rebooting until I manually go through each directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, bookmarks

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I bookmarked my second partition (I named it D) in the file manager so it can be easily accessible. Unfortunately, every time I reboot the computer, it seems that the bookmarked link crashes. I fix it by opening the specific directory by going in "+Other Locations" and clicking on it. Also I had a shortcut for a cloned repository from github, which I couldn't access too after rebooting. Is there anyway I can fix that so I don't need to do this every time I turn on my PC.
[image]

Comment: This is not Windows - you don't **need** partitions to be alphabetical. Does your partition have a file system and is it mounted during boot? Is your link to your download of github a symbolic link?

Comment: fixed it by checking off the user session defaults option and leaving the tick on "mount at start up" in the mount option of the specified partition (gnome-disks)